# On the proof of Weils hyperelliptic theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a large prime. Consider $F_p$
Theorem:

Let $P$ be an element in $F_p[x]$ of degree $k$, assume that $P$ is not a constant multiple of a square. Then the number of solutions $(x,y)$ in $(F_p)^2$ to $y^2 = P(x)$ is $p+O_k(\sqrt p)$

A proof of this result can be found in:
https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/the-least-quadratic-nonresidue-and-the-square-root-barrier/#more-2664

The proof uses the polynomial method, defining the polynomial $Q(x) = P^l(R(x,x^p)+P^{(p-1)/2}S(x,x^p))$ for $l\cong \sqrt p$ and polys $R(x,z),S(x,z)$ satisfying some degree condition. Then one shows you can choose such $S,R$ so that for each $x$ with $P(x)$ a square, $Q$ vanishes at least $l$ times.

I don't understand why we need to multiply by $P^l$, why doesn't Terry's  argument go through even without it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have the time to look it up now, but sounds like he is explaining the Stepanov (or Schmidt-Stepanov) method of deriving the bound. A detailed explanation of that is in Lidl & Niederreiter (as well as Schmidt's *Equations over finite fields* from Springer Lecture Notes series). Probably this factor is needed to get the zeros of $P(x)$ included, and the other factor handles non-zero squares only.

Comment: Bombieri has rewritten the argument using the language of divisors (may be also other fine tuning, I'm afraid I have never thoroughly compared the two approaches). Stichtenoth's book titled approximately *Function fields and codes* describes it in that language.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree it makes the roots of $P$ work (they wouldn't work really if we didn't do this), but since there are at most $k$, and our error is anyways $O_k(\sqrt p)$, it just seems weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it's actually stupid:

We want the derivative to also be of the form with $P^((p-1)/2)$, and a way to promise that is multiply by $P^l$ and give copies of it when taking the derivative.